# Getting the rclcpp::Duration in microseconds

Tags: ros, ros2, c++, rclcpp, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I am trying to calculate the time it takes for a single message from one Node to get to the other Node.

The way I calculate the difference is by substituting the timestamp of the received message from the present time of the node (*rclcpp::Node::now()*) and store it as *rclcpp::Duration*. Next, I convert the *rclcpp::Duration* to *std::chrono::duration* of microseconds, so that I can store it later in *uint64_t*. There is a method to achieve this as described [here](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Duration.html#a671704beeb2de5c6b48b4082c38a7804).

However, I seem to not understand, will this conversion convert only the nanoseconds? (assuming the *seconds()* represent amount of seconds since epoch, and *nanoseconds()* represent nanoseconds from seconds). Should I then separately convert seconds and nanoseconds, convert them to microseconds and then sum up?

Or, the *to_chrono()* converts both seconds and nanoseconds (ie total time since epoch) in nanoseconds?

The code is below:

```
void inputCallback(const digital_twin_msgs::msg::SupplyInput::SharedPtr msg)
    {
      if(msg->seq_id == p_input_sub->next_id) {
        p_input_sub->recv_counter += 1;
        rclcpp::Duration diff = rclcpp::Node::now() - msg->stamp;
        auto num_of_us = diff.to_chrono<std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::micro>>(); // <- is this total time since epoch in microseconds?
        uint64_t var = num_of_us.count();
        p_input_sub->time_diffs.push_back(var);
      }else{
        p_input_sub->lost_count += 1;
      }
      p_input_sub->next_id = msg->seq_id + 1;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399382/getting-the-rclcpp::duration-in-microseconds/) by [sejego](https://answers.ros.org/users/60631/sejego/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2022-04-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, what you're getting is the time in microseconds. May I suggest one QoL change to that line:

```
auto num_of_us = diff.to_chrono<std::chrono::microseconds>();
```

---

Originally posted by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) with karma: 456 on 2022-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2022-04-21**:
To answer the rest of the question. No, the `nanoseconds` function won't only convert the nanoseconds.
`nanoseconds` returns the full time period represented by the `rclcpp::Duration` object in nanoseconds, as does `seconds` in seconds. There's usually a lot of accuracy lost with the latter, so I'd suggest sticking to the former, or better, to `to_chrono`.

**Comment by [sejego](https://answers.ros.org/users/60631/sejego/) on 2022-04-22**:
Great! Thank you for the QoL change and for explanation, that is exactly what I need :) . I wish I had the experience to know these kinds of little details regarding std::chrono types. It indeed looks much clearer.

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2022-04-22**:
No worries. Slight tangent, but if you want to learn about `std::chrono` specifically, this video will take you a long way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M